# Can I verify if a person is smiling using Kinect gestures ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, kinect, gestures

I'm trying to figure out if I can verify if a person is smiling using Kinect gestures. I got Face Tracking Basics-WPF(Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit 1.8.0) project and as well I found something about some Animation Units(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx at the middle of the webpage you'll find a tabel ) and how a flag is returned if for example a person is neutral=0,very happy smile=-1,very sad frown=+1.

The question is: What function from Face Tracking Basics-WPF project is returning that value(-1,0,1) and if someone can write a sample of code that verifies if a person is neutral etc and return a message ( "You're happy" or "You're sad " ) .

THANKS ! HAVE A NICE DAY

Comment: My guess after poking at the reference is that it's [`IFTResult::GetAUCoefficients`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.facetracking.iftresult.getaucoefficients.aspx). And it doesn't return a flag, it returns a number between -1 and 1 that describes where the given points on a face are compared to the neutral position.

Comment: Oh ... ok milimoose, I found that method. A simply "if" that verifies if the value of GetAUCoefficients is -1 or 1 should be enough to return a message "You're smiling" "You're not smiling" ?

Comment: I just poked at the docs, I have neither the experience nor hardware to verify this. Write your code, find out what values you get when you smile and frown at the camera, use those later. I wouldn't expect exactly -1 or +1, it will probably depend on your face etc.

Comment: Ok I'll try to figure it out and I'll come back with an answer